# How to pass more than one parameter in custom newsletter programmatically in magento 2 below codes are shown?

Tags: magento2

Actually here i am trying to pass 3 parameters in subscribe function(firstname,lastname,email)data is coming but some error it is showing,
If anyone has idea please guide me.

Controller file

```
namespace Bathintime\Shop\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Subscribe extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $subscriberFactory;
    protected $messageManager;
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager) {
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        echo "1";
            $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe(['email'=>$post['email']]);
            echo "2";
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("You are subscribed successfully."));
            echo "3";
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            echo "4";
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            echo "5";
            return $resultRedirect;
            echo "6";


    }
}
```

Error File

```
{"0":"Class Dotdigitalgroup\\Email\\Model\\AutomationFactory does not exist","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Newsletter\/Model\/Subscriber\/Interceptor.php(245): Magento\\Newsletter\\Model\\Subscriber->subscribe('test123@gmail.c...')\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/app\/code\/Bathintime\/Shop\/Controller\/Index\/Subscribe.php(25): Magento\\Newsletter\\Model\\Subscriber\\Interceptor->subscribe('test123@gmail.c...')\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/generated\/code\/Bathintime\/Shop\/Controller\/Index\/Subscribe\/Interceptor.php(24): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe->execute()\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe\\Interceptor->execute()\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#6 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/generated\/code\/Bathintime\/Shop\/Controller\/Index\/Subscribe\/Interceptor.php(39): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#8 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Bathintime\\Shop\\Controller\\Index\\Subscribe\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#9 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#11 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#16 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#17 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#18 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#19 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#20 \/var\/www\/html\/bathintime\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#21 {main}","url":"\/bathintime\/shop\/index\/subscribe\/","script_name":"\/bathintime\/index.php"}
```